# Save WP search query as href in member area

Tags: javascript, wordpress, search

Looking more for guidance than solution on accomplishing this - so any advice helps!

Using s2member to create a member area for login, and ideally would have an area on that login page with a list of saved search strings on that same WP site.

Example:

I go to mysite.com and do a search for 'dog', which results in the below URL:

mysite.com/?s=dog

Ideally, the user should be able to click on a button somewhere on the page that saves the search query/URL to their member login page as either an href to click on and view.

Got a current button with some Javascript that allows a user to save the current search query/URL, so hoping to extend out that function or build on it in another function to accomplish this.

Example of copy URL code I'm working with:

```
 <div id="copy"><i class="fa fa-clipboard" aria-hidden="true"></i> Copy Search</div>
```

Function:

```
            // Copies a string to the clipboard
        function copyToClipboard(text) {
            if (window.clipboardData && window.clipboardData.setData) {
                // IE specific code path to prevent textarea being shown while dialog is visible.
                return clipboardData.setData("Text", text); 

            } else if (document.queryCommandSupported && document.queryCommandSupported("copy")) {
                var textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
                textarea.textContent = text;
                textarea.style.position = "fixed";  // Prevent scrolling to bottom of page in MS Edge.
                document.body.appendChild(textarea);
                textarea.select();
                try {
                    return document.execCommand("copy");  // Security exception may be thrown by some browsers.
                } catch (ex) {
                    console.warn("Copy to clipboard failed.", ex);
                    return false;
                } finally {
                    document.body.removeChild(textarea);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could save the keyword in users session with php:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['s']) {
    $_SESSION['search'] = $_GET['s'];
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

When a user hits the search page, you can do something to the effect of this, although you might need to change it to suit your needs.

**HTML**

```
<input type="hidden" name="user_id" id="user_id" value="1" />

<input type="hidden" name="save_search_term" id="save_search_term" value="writing a blog" />
```

**PHP**

```
// use as a fallback, can be provided in request
$user_id = get_current_user_id();

// sanitize this
$search_term = $_POST['s'];

// replaces existing meta if 'saved_search' already exists
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'saved_search', $search_term );
```

It's probably best that with the submit button, you also include two hidden input boxes to capture this data as it might be skewed/lost in the request. So you would grab the data from the input boxes using JavaScript and post that data to the PHP handler to save the user meta.

Of course, be very careful what data you save to your database when capturing fields like that as people can alter them in a malicious way. I think `update_user_meta` will add it to the database safely, but even so, people could add a fake user id so make sure you check it.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel! I was able to get a variation of this working. My only question is, since this only seems to hold one piece of data at a time, how would it be set up to record say, up to five pieces of data? In other words, does the update_user_meta track such a thing or would it have to be set up in some sort of function?

Comment: Well it depends what you want to do with the data, but you could always include more hidden input fields and fill them with data.